# Facebook comments module doesn't show comments on desktop

Tags: facebook, wordpress, comments

I'm quite puzzled here. I have facebook comments on this site and I can see in the moderation section that comments are going through fine. However when I load the page on desktop (or tablet, we server the same version of the page to tablets) it says 0 comments.

If you load the page on mobile (or even simulate phone on Chrome), the comments show up fine.
I have no idea how to even start to debug this, any ideas?

Example page with comments: removed due to solved

Has anyone had a similar problem? I mean probably the problem is somewhere in the code, but I just can't pinpoint it for the life of me. I have all the FB meta tags that are needed, I have the

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&appId=<?php echo($options["theme"]["facebook_app_id"]); ?>&version=v2.0";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

and then finally the form itself

```
<div class="fb-comments" data-href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" data-width="100%" data-numposts="50"></div>
```

all these copied straight from the developer.facebook tools except the app_id (I have multiple sites that use the same code). I even tried to hard code the appids in place but that didn't help.

All help really appreciated.

edit: Thought that maybe it's just me and went ahead and installed Facebook Comments by Fat Panda plugin, but the problem persists. No comments on desktop, only works on mobile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I emulate a mobile device (I chose Google Nexus 4 at random) in Chrome, the `data-href` attribute of the `<div class="fb-like">` element is set to

```
http://www.suomikiekko.com/2014/08/ilja-kovaltshuk-ei-nimea-jokereita-pietarin-skan-paavastustajaksi/
```

– same address as the article I’m viewing.

When I view the site in desktop mode however, the `data-href` attribute of the comments plugin is set to

```
http://www.suomikiekko.com/2014/09/tassa-on-jokerien-historiallisen-khl-kauden-kapteenisto/
```

– so that seems to be the URL to a completely different article. The URL in the address bar is still the first one though, and the content seems to be the same as in the mobile view as well.

And of course, different URLs mean different Open Graph objects that the comments are associated with.

---

I can not actually look at the source code when in mobile emulation mode, so that `data-href` value is only what I see in DOM inspector – but I would assume that it is not the comments plugin that messes with this, but rather that your site is doing some kind of desktop/mobile detection and delivering different HTML based on that. So I’d suggest you investigate further in that direction – try and figure out what could possibly make your CMS deliver a wrong `data-href` attribute when the page is viewed on desktop.

Comment: I'm sure I did check this though! But seems you're right.
For some reason that data-href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" spills out the wrong url entirely...

Back to debugging. So thanks mate!

Comment: Yeah. I changed it to <?php echo('http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']); ?> and it works like a charm. Seems I've messed up my loop at some point and forgot to wp_reset_postdata(); or something. This almost should be over at the WordPress StackExchange but anyway, glad to get it sorted!

Comment: That does not seem to be the best approach though … when users click on a link to your page from other sources, there will often be tracking parameters appended to your URL (f.e. Facebook itself does that with links shared by its users) – and `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` will just pass those through 1:1, which ends up with the comments plugin getting a “wrong” URL set as `data-href` again. Take that first URL – I can see the comments in desktop view as well now – but as soon as I append f.e. `?foo=bar` to the end of it, they are “gone” again …

Comment: So I think this might justify a little more investigation – so that in the end you have a solid fix, rather then a _somehow working, but only almost_-kind of workaround … Do you have any plugins installed that have the job of delivering different content for desktop vs mobile? If so, I’d suggest disabling those one-by-one to try and figure out which one might actually be to blame here.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. Well now that it works at least most of the time I have time to investigate what breaks the permalink command. Thank you non the less.

Comment: You’re welcome. Keep us posted if you find anything. (Or if we can offer additional help, in case you find something that seems to be causing this, but don’t know what exactly to do about it.)

Comment: Yeah I'll wrap this up now, as we shouldn't 'chat' in comments.

But the problem was one of my secondary loops that had the wp_reset_postdata(); on a wrong line and thus the link that the_permalink() outputted was the last post on that loop.

It's all fixed now and works with or without ?foo=bars :)

Comment: Well glad to hear you got it all working correctly now!